# Importar rango de otro libro usando validación de datos en Google Sheets

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Quiero hacer una lista desplegable en un libro llamado sheet front end:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXyJh.png]

Pero el rango está en otro libro llamado sheet with range:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqCQT.png]

He estado tratando de usar validación de datos junto con `IMPORTRAGE` sin éxito, haciendo lo siguiente:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A8v4TEgibkesX729YcjEDn8RkcogutT_8pgIkggaBfI/edit#gid=0", "Hoja 1!A1:A5)
```

Y obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcflk.png]

Comment: En tu trozo de codigo te faltan unas comillas al final, ha sido error al copiarlo o te faltan en tu intento real tambien?

Comment: a sido un error al ponerlo aqui. . no me funciona.  Yo podria poner esa columna (one, two . . )  en el mismo libro ( en otra hoja ) pero lo que quiero es algo centralizado que cuando haga varias copias de "sheet fron end" o que cuando agregue mas datos a la columna, por ejemplo six, seven, automaticamente se actualice en sheet fron end